# Where has Pearl seen this vending machine before?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

After shopping on a Vending-Machine floor, Pearl commented "Where have I seen that vending machine before?"

Why did Pearl make this comment? Where has she seen this vending machine before? What's so special about it that she would remember seeing it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's exactly the same vending machine appearing in Splatoon 2:

[image]

But it could also be a joke about the fact that you have to replay the same floors again and again, since this mode is a roguelite. If Pearl Drone has no memory of the previous runs, the vending machine is a sort of déjà vu.